# What is the limit of number of queries can sql handle?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Guys I'm trying to update my table which have 60 thousand rows, and this is my code:

just ignore the logic of the code, just take a look at the number of queries it has and the loops. I', planning to put a limit to the main query but I want it to be the maximum limit of SQL so that I can save time. Any idea guys?

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(nid) FROM `comment` LIMIT ");
//mysql_query("UPDATE comment set thread = '00/' WHERE pid = 0 and uid = 333333");

while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $query2=mysql_query("SELECT cid,pid,thread FROM comment WHERE nid = ".$result['nid']." ORDER by created");

    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){ 

    $nodethread = 0;


        if($result2['pid'] == 0)
            $thread = int2vancode($nodethread) . "/";


        else{           

            $parent = (string) rtrim((string) $result2['thread'], '/');
            $parent=explode('.',$parent);
            echo $parent." this is parent</br>";

            $max=max($parent);

            if($max == '')
            {
            $thread = $result['thread'].'.'.int2vancode(0) .'/';
            }
            else
            {
                  //$parts = explode('.', $max);
                  $parent_depth = count($parent);
                  echo "parent".$parent_depth;
                  $last = $parent[$parent_depth];
                  $thread = $result2['thread'] .'.'. int2vancode(vancode2int($last) + 1) .'/';
            }


        }
        mysql_query("UPDATE comment set thread = '$thread' where cid = ".$result2['cid']."");

    }

}
```

SO to summarize my code, I have first a:

```
while loop for my first query
then i have another while loop inside for my second query
and lastly i have an update inside.
```

Comment: The upper limit will depend on many factors - some of which are the language used, the libraries used, the hardware, the database software, tuning done, operating system these are running on, the network conditions and more. In short - you want to find out? Test it.

Comment: infinite if you use it the right way.

Comment: @Prix so can you take a look at my queries in my code cause i have no idea what is that "right way" youre speaking of

Comment: I would start by not using mysql_* as suggested on php.net manual.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: between 0 and infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I think you're trying to get at is *concurrency*.

`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` operations require locks to be able to run. MyISAM tables will lock the entire table while these run, while InnoDB usually only locks the affected rows. If a query runs that need access to these tables/rows, even a `SELECT`, it will be queued until the lock is removed.

You seem to be firing off a squillion tiny queries which *should* be OK, so long as it doesn't matter if other queries run in between. If it's *not* OK, then you need to switch to InnoDB and use transactions. But, as it stands, you're probably not going to have much issue with concurrent queries slowing each other down.

Comment: I get your concept now bro, To isolate a certain query that needs priority i should use locking of tables right? But what you saw in my queries is it doesnt need locking? right again? but why is it when i execute my query without limit, that is executing all 60k rows, i get this error  ---->>> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\vancode\vancode.php on line 78

Comment: @Zaski [`set_time_limit()` and/or `max_execution_time` in php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)